# Complex bundles on $S^{2n+1}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, topological-k-theory

We know that the  complex  $K$ theory of  spheres are 2 periodic. On the other hand every  complex  bundle on $S^{1}$ is trivial. So  $K(S^{2n+1})=0$. So this is a  motivation to  ask: Is there  a  non trivial  complex  bundle  on $S^{2n+1}$  for  some  $n$?

Answer (score 1):

[Qiaochu Yuan](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/865520/visual-interpretation-of-the-bott-periodicity-for-complex-vector-bundles/865785#865785):

> Bott (I think?) proved that $\pi_{2n}(U(n)) \cong [S^{2n-1}, BU(n)] \cong \mathbb{Z}_{n!}$, so the odd spheres $S^{2n-1}$ have nontrivial $n$-dimensional complex vector bundles on them for all $n \ge 2$.